# BLE devices with AWS IOT gateway

Tags: aws-iot, aws-greengrass

I am building a setup for 1-10 wearable sensors (all in range) to send data over BLE to:

1. co-located android device app for each sensor
2. AWS EC2 for further processing and web app serving. a dashboard to see all data

Does the choice of greengrass core device - a simple laptop vs one of the supported edge devices - simply come down to whether I need lambda functions? are there other reasons to avoid laptop?

Comment: Just use a RPi. Greengrass suported, cheap and perhaps powerful enough.

Comment: interesting. and I guess for a hub, form factor doesn't matter. it can be as big as an actual raspberry pie, just want it easy to setup and configure, and powerful enough to do some processing